# Reading HttpURLConnection InputStream - manual buffer or BufferedInputStream?

Tags: buffer, inputstream, httpurlconnection, bufferedinputstream

When reading the InputStream of an HttpURLConnection, is there any reason to use one of the following over the other? I've seen both used in examples.

**Manual Buffer:**

```
while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    os.write(buf, 0, ret);
}
```

**BufferedInputStream**

```
is = http.getInputStream();
bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);

int current = 0;
while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
     baf.append(current);
}
```

**EDIT** I'm still new to HTTP in general but one consideration that comes to mind is that if I am using a persistent HTTP connection, I can't just read until the input  stream is empty right? In that case, wouldn't I need to read the message length and just read the input stream for that length?

And similarly, if NOT using a persistent connection, is the code I included 100% good to go in terms of reading the stream properly?

Comment: What is `ByteArrayBuffer`? But there is never any reason to deal in single bytes when you could be dealing in byte arrays.

Answer (score 5):

I talk about a good way to do it on my blog in a post about using JSON in android. http://blog.andrewpearson.org/2010/07/android-why-to-use-json-and-how-to-use.html.  I will post the relevant part of the relevant post below (the code is pretty generalizable):

```
InputStream in = null;
String queryResult = "";
try {
     URL url = new URL(archiveQuery);
     HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
     HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) urlConn;
     httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
     httpConn.connect();
     in = httpConn.getInputStream();
     BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(in);
     ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
     int read = 0;
     int bufSize = 512;
     byte[] buffer = new byte[bufSize];
     while(true){
          read = bis.read(buffer);
          if(read==-1){
               break;
          }
          baf.append(buffer, 0, read);
     }
     queryResult = new String(baf.toByteArray());
     } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
          // DEBUG
          Log.e("DEBUG: ", e.toString());
     } catch (IOException e) {
          // DEBUG
          Log.e("DEBUG: ", e.toString());
     }
}
```

Comment: There is one definite but to fix: you should always specify encoding to use for converting bytes to String (new String(baf.toByteArray(), "UTF-8").

Answer (score 2):

Regarding persistent HTTP connections it is just the opposite. You **should read everything from the input stream**. Otherwise the Java HTTP client does not know that the HTTP request is complete and the socket connection can be reused.

See http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-keepalive.html:

> What can you do to help with Keep-Alive?
>
> Do not abandon a connection by
>   ignoring the response body. Doing so
>   may results in idle TCP connections.
>   That needs to be garbage collected
>   when they are no longer referenced.
>
> If getInputStream() successfully
>   returns, read the entire response
>   body.

Answer (score 0):

Use former -- latter has no real benefits over first one, and is bit slower; reading things byte by byte is inefficient even if buffered (although horribly slow when not buffered). That style of reading input went out of vogue with C; although may be useful in cases where you need to find an end marker of some sort.

Answer (score -1):

Only if you're using the `BufferedInputStream`-specific methods.

Comment: Further clarification added to question.

Comment: The `BufferedInputStream`-specific methods such as what? It doesn't export any methods other than those defined by `InputStream`.