# Every HTTP request uses a separate TCP connection

Tags: http, tcp, jboss, persistent

**Observations:**

- My web app is running in JBoss.
- Every single user-click generates >5 HTTP requests because of images etc.
- Running netstat on the server reveals that a new TCP connection is being opened for every single HTTP request (basically I am looking at the total number of TCP connections from the client IP on port 80).

**Facts:**

- JBoss HTTP protocol is set at 1.1.
- I have checked with FF, IE9 and Chrome - and all browsers do the same.
- I have two test environments - one running on Windows7 and the other one running on CentOS. I see the same behavior in both.

**What I am trying to accomplish**

- Persistent TCP connection, because hopefully that would a) enhance user experience and b) reduce load on the server

At this point, I am not sure what code, configuration details or log I should attach to the question, but if you let me know, I will provide it. Any kind of help is appreciated.

p.s. This thread seemed promising from the title [TCP connection is not reused for HTTP requests with HttpURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459162/tcp-connection-is-not-reused-for-http-requests-with-httpurlconnection), but it deals mainly with the client side.

Comment: Can you look at the traffic? Can you check the Connection HTTP headers that the client and server send?

Comment: Hi Philippe, thanks for the reply. Which header items should I look at? I would probably be doing it using the HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse getHeader(String header) methods. If there is a quicker way to do it, I would be interested to learn about that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @PhilippeMarschall Request header: checked the following items 1) Cookie -> JSESSIONID=blah-blah, 2) Connection -> keep-alive, 3) Cache-Control -> null, 4) pragma -> null

Comment: What I usually use is a combination of tcpdumpd and Wireshark and then follow the tcpstream.  This allows me to see what requests are made over a tcp connection. Then I look at the Close header http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.10 both sent by the client and the server. I look for a "Connection: close" header. Does the client or server send one?

Comment: A browser side tool like firebug, fiddler or httpwatch will also give you that data.

Comment: Partially, the headers are already parsed and you don't see where a tcp connection starts and where it ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found a solution to this. Thanks for the pointers and the suggestions. They really helped.

Part 1:
I used the HttpFox plugin in Firefox to look at the response headers. As Philippe suspected the Connection header had a value of "close".

Part 2:
Adding a line of code in my own filter to change the response header did not help. So I downloaded and added jbossWebService.jar to the WEB-INF/lib directory in order to use the org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter class. (Prior to JBoss 7, apparently this package used to be included in JBoss by default.) Added the following in my web.xml:

```
<filter>

<filter-name>CommonHeadersFilter</filter-name>

<filter-class>

org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter</filter-class>

<init-param>

     <param-name>Connection</param-name>

     <param-value>keep-alive</param-value>

</init-param>

</filter>
```

This did the trick (well, almost). Now, the first "click" from the browser generates about 4 TCP connections - not sure about the reason for that number, because every single click generates >=7 http requests. But all subsequent clicks, if performed within the ttl period (15 s), do not generate additional TCP connections. I guess a more thorough investigation, as suggested by Philippe, would reveal something. But at this point I have to move on. So, for the time being I will mark this question as answered. If needed in the future, I will re-open it.

Comment: Most modern browsers open up to 4-8 simultaneous connections per hostname, to speed up loading multiple files from the same host. You can find detailed information on the behavior of each browser on [Browserscope](http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network&v=top).

Comment: @MartinodF This is very informative and helpful (your comment as well as the Browserscope project)! Thank you very much! I will now consider this problem to be solved.